# Simple expansion

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Why this works:

```
TrigExpand[Sin[2 T - 2 \[Tau]cr \[Omega]cr]]
```

while this doesn't work

```
(Sin[2*T - 2*\[Tau]cr*\[Omega]cr]) /. 
any_[a_ - b_] :> TrigExpand[any[a - b]]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mathematica uses `FullForm` when comparing patterns.

```
(Sin[2*T - 2*\[Tau]cr*\[Omega]cr]) /. 
 any_[Plus[a_, b_]] :> TrigExpand[any[a + b]]
```

> ```
> 2 Cos[T] Cos[\[Tau]cr \[Omega]cr]^2 Sin[T] - 
>  2 Cos[T]^2 Cos[\[Tau]cr \[Omega]cr] Sin[\[Tau]cr \[Omega]cr] + 
>  2 Cos[\[Tau]cr \[Omega]cr] Sin[T]^2 Sin[\[Tau]cr \[Omega]cr] - 
>  2 Cos[T] Sin[T] Sin[\[Tau]cr \[Omega]cr]^2
> ```